# how to make variable visibility in block statement in Python?

Tags: python

How to achieve an effect like :

```
#there is no variable named `i`
for i in range(1):
    pass
print(i) #why
```

I don't want to make `i` visitable after the `for` statement finished.

But I don't want to use `del i` manually.

Comment: The way you remove a name from a namespace is with the `del` statement.  There is no magic here.  Python has its visibility rules, and you need to learn to work with them.

Comment: Apparently you switched from another language? In python, you can't do this without rewriting the kernel, because it's not necessary. If you don't need "i" anymore, just don't use it and there won't be any problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts I understand. it looks illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just part of Python's design. A `for` loop assigns to `i` on each iteration, just as if it did `i = next(some_iterator)`. Just like any other assignment, the `i` variable persists until it gets rebound to something else, or until you remove it with `del i`.

Variables in Python are not (usually) limited to a single block, only functions (and a few other language constructs built out of them, like comprehensions and generator expressions) have their own scopes in that way. This is different than other programming languages that have a more expansive form of lexical scoping, where each block can have its own scope. (The one exception is exception handling code, `except SomeExeptionType as e`, where the `e` variable gets deleted after the end of the block, to help avoid reference loops between exception tracebacks and stack frames.)

If you want to be sure you don't leak any variables, put all your code into separate functions. Local variables will never leak outside of their function.

```
def do_a_loop():
    for i in range(1):
        pass
    # i is still defined here, but only until the end of the function body

do_a_loop()
print(i)     # this will raise, as i is not defined as a global variable
```